# Laravel: How to add number of days to a date?

Tags: php, laravel, date, controller

I have a form, where I insert the start_date field (date format) and I want to auto assign the end_date (+180 days) through controller, before store.

My store controller is very simple:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $ticket = Ticket::find($id);
    return view('tickets.show', compact('ticket'));
}
```

Equal my update controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $ticket = Ticket::find($id);
    $ticket->fill($request->all())->save();
    return redirect()->route('tickets.show', $ticket->id)->with('info', 'Datos actualizados con éxito');
}
```

Do you any idea?

Comment: There is no store method in your code. You've provided show method.

Answer (score 2):

Put this line after you initialize `Ticket` object:

```
$ticket->end_date = $request->input('start_date')->addDays($numDays);
```

edit-01:

in your model: define the following code.

`protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'start_date`'];

Comment: **addDays** is a function from Carbon, but I don´t have this in my system. There are other way?

Comment: @Drennos, Laravel ships with Carbon. You should have this.

Comment: I have this message: **Call to a member function addDays() on string**

Comment: you could set the $ticket->end_date with the $request->input('start_date') value. 

After that update Ticket like the $ticket->end_date = $ticket->end_date->addDays(180); because in the Model it should be a Carbon object

Answer (score 1):

First [convert your string to DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php), then do

```
$date->add(new \DateInterval('P180D'));
```